# davfs2: file "disappear" and end up as lost+found/.goutputstream-XXX

Tags: davfs2

Recently, I noticed a very strange (and very *annoying*) bug in Ubuntu 18.04 (not sure which package causes it): I have a remote webdav drive mounted using `mount.davfs`, and sometimes files saved on that drive disappear.

I have several different types of files saved on that drive, but only markdown files seem to be affected by it. However, note that these markdown files are also the only files that I edit (using Vim and Gedit).

Whatever the cause of this might be, I noticed that those files all ended up in lost+found, renamed to `.goutputstrema-XXX`.

**Q**: Can anybody replicate? Which program create files with the ending `.goutputstream-XXX`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing something very similar, but only with .jpg files, and the names in lost+found look like:

```
2019-04-16_Staples_business_laptop.jpg-47BABQ
.2019-04-16_Staples_business_laptop.jpg.EbARnY-DhpL11
```

(i.e. have base64? suffixes of 6 or 12 chars, and possibly a '.' prefix)

**Fix (at least on my system)**

As suggested by man davfs2.conf, edit `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` and uncomment and change the lines with `use_locks` and `drop_weak_etags` to:

```
use_locks 0
drop_weak_etags 1
```

Then unmount and remount your WebDAV folder.

This is safe for me because it is a single-user WebDAV folder that is only written to from one machine at a time, but YMMV.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! This provides a solution, so it counts as an answer.